# .htaccess point specific domain home to internal page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Okay...i am doing something kinda strange and out of the ordinary.  I will try to explain...

I have several domain names pointed to the same root directory on my webserver.  I can access the entire website using any of the domain names (I know this is bad for SEO, but there are reasons).  Additionally, none of the "pages" really exist...as they are all being built dynamically...so i have some mod rewrite rules set up to point all incoming queries to view.php and passing in variables to generate the page content...anyway...

What i want to do is set ONLY THE HOME PAGE of two of my domains to (invisibly) use content of an existing sub page.  Here is an example:

These all are the same page:
www.domain1.com/process/
www.domain2.com/process/
www.domain3.com/process/
which is really doing something like:  view.php?page=process/

I want this page to display for www.domain2.com (and still also be accessible at domain2.com/process)

Essentially, there is a sub page of the site that i want to serve as the "HOME" page for domain2.com and domain3.com but if domain1.com should still use the default (index.php) HOME page.

I am sure i will need to post clarifications to this once replies start coming in...but here is what i have at the moment:

```
# special rules to set other domain names default homepage as specific internal page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ /view.php?page=process/ [NC,L]
```

Currently this is sending ALL traffic to domain2.com to the "process/" page...so it is blocking out all other pages. I need to know how to have this rule ONLY apply to the base domain without any extra query string or url path.  The key is that i DO NOT want to affect other pages within the domain...so i shoudl still be able to browse the whole site using this domain name...i just get started on a different view.

Comment: I suppose what i am looking for is a LITERAL comparison to "www.domain2.com" rather than a regex that allows for characters AFTER this to be captured and used in the rule.

Comment: I also have tried a literal using the following...and it still matches...but it is matching all URLs within the domain and sending them all to the special HOME page:  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \Qwww.domain2.com\E  [NC]

Comment: So, you want to exclude few URLs from domain2.com ?

Comment: i want to be able to still access all pages from all of the domains...so nothing is EXCLUDED...  I am trying to just route the HOME page of certain domains to a specific page

Comment: Say you have 4 domain d1.com, d2.com, d3.com and d4.com. Out those 4, home page of d1.com and d2.com redirects to some specific page and d3.com d4.com remains as it is. Is that what you want?

Comment: @OhhMee - yes...except no actual redirection (like 301 or the such)...just serve the alternate content for the home page on a couple of the domains...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To only match the homepage, i.e. `http://domain2com/` you need to match the empty path (as mod_Rewrite removes the leading `/`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /view.php?page=process/ [NC,L]
```

Comment: perfect.  thanks.  Not sure why yours works and mine did not...but this is working.

Comment: Your rule matches any url, while mine just matches the home-url.